# How to create new (unsaved) Django model with associations?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm building a "preview" function into the CMS for my website which uses the existing front-end template to render a model.  This model has an association:

```
class FeatureWork(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...

class FeatureWorkLink(models.Model):
    feature_work = models.ForeignKey(FeatureWork)
```

In the view for the preview, I'm trying to build the model such that when the template calls feature.featureworklink_set.all it returns the associated links.  Since neither model has been saved yet, all the standard Django form techniques seem to go out the window.

This is what I have so far, but it blows up when I call the add method on the manager, since the parent hasn't been saved yet:

```
form = FeatureWorkAdminForm(initial=request.POST)
featured = form.save(commit=False)
for link in request.POST['links'].split(","):
    featured.featureworklink_set.add(FeatureWorkLink(image=link))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just add:

preview = BooleanField()

to your models, save everything to database and don't look for hacks. This way you can have drafts for free.

Comment: Yeah, that's actually pretty much how I implemented it.  You can't use the preview mode until the instance is saved.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually save it in transaction and rollback when template is ready. It's not very efficient, but at least it will work.

Answer (score 0):

`featured.featureworklink_set.add(FeatureWorkLink(image=link))` will immediately attempt to create a relationship between a `FeatureWork` and `FeatureWorkLink`, which isn't going to happen because that instance of `FeatureWork` is not present in the database and you cannot satisfy the predicates for building the foreign key relationship.

But the great thing is that Django's `Model` and `ModelForm` instances will not validate foreign key relationships until your actually trying to commit the data. So manually constructing your `FeaturedWorkLink` with an uncommited, non-existing `FeatureWork` should satisfy any presentation of the data you need to do, much to what you'd expect:

```
 links = []
 form = FeatureWorkAdminForm(initial=request.POST)
 featured = form.save(commit=False)

 for link in request.POST['links'].split(","):
      links.add(FeatureWorkLink(image=link, feature_work=featured))

 # then somewhere in your templates, from the context

 {% for link in links %}
      <img src="{{ link.image }}" 
       title="Image for the featured work: '{{ link.feature_work.name }}'" />
 {% endfor %}
```

So basically, during the course of collecting the data to create a `FeatureWork`, you'll have to maintain the `FeatureWorkLink` instances through subsequent requests. This is where you'd use a model form set, but provide an uncommitted `FeatureWork` for the `feature_work` property for every model form instance of the set, up until the point where all the data has been collected, where you then provide a commited `FeatureWork` instance, so that the model form set can satisfy referential integrity and finally be commited to the database.